# Ionic 4 Pass parameter to another page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Please help how to pass param to another page in ionc 4?

As the push and navparam function seen not working anymore in ionic4.

https://medium.com/@muthudevendra/ionic-sharing-data-between-pages-8d0412cb8f58

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Page1.ts`

```
public country: string;
  public email: string;
  public password: string;   

constructor(public nav: NavController) {}

goToAboutPage() {
    let params: any = {
      country: this.country,
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password
    }
    this.nav.navigateForward('/identity', { state: params }); // params to pass object/array
  }
```

`Page2.ts`

```
constructor(public router: Router){
if (router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
      const params = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
console.log(params.email)
console.log(params.password)
console.log(params.country) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in page.html use like this:

```
<ion-button routerLink="/yourAddress" [queryParams]="{ paramName : 'paramValue' }" ></ion-button>
```

---

in page.ts use like this:

```
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/yourAddress?paramName=' + this.paramValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read up on Activated route and NavigationExtras,

on page.ts have a function probably binded to a click event

```
goToNextpage() {
    let navigationExtras : NavigationExtras = { state: { dataToBePassed:this.param }};
    this.router.navigate(['/nextpage'], navigationExtras);
  }
```

on nextpage.ts
`import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';`
and do your dependency injection in the constructor like

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    ) { 
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
        
        this.var = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.dataToBePassed;      
      }
      console.log(this.var); // will get you the data passed with key dataToBePassed
    });
  }
```